# Stored procedure insert if column contains then rollback

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure where data gets inserted to a table, however there is only certain data allowed to be inserted. How do I rollback/cancel the sp if a certain column contains certain characters (ex: xyz)?

Comment: Why rollback?  Just check the condition before and don;t do the insert if your condition is met?

Comment: Show what you have tried first please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should probably just show us the code.  Failing that, How are you finding out that the column contains invalid characters?

Comment: How about a check constraint? `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint CHECK (mycolumn NOT LIKE '%xyz%');`

Comment: Yes.. forget about client side logic and rollbacks. Just use a check constraint to ensure it's not allowed in

Answer (score 1):

`COMMIT`s and `ROLLBACK`s are much better handled by the client application than inside a stored procedure. The only exception to this is if your DBMS supports rolling back to a savepoint that was defined within the procedure.

As for the stored procedure inserting the data, you can `INSERT` the results of a `SELECT` statement that uses a `WHERE` clause to specify your data validation criteria. This approach removes the need for a looping structure if you are evaluating and inserting multiple rows.

```
INSERT INTO targetTable ( col1, col2, col3, ...)
   SELECT 
       f1, f2, f3, ... 
   FROM 
       someTableOrJoinOrExpression
   WHERE 
       someColumn NOT LIKE '%xyz%' 
       AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FOR cycle to only insert the values need.
declare

```
begin

for i in (select * from table1) loop
if i.field1 != 'xyz' then
   insert into table2 
   values (i.field1,....,field10)
else
  //You can do any other action 
end if;

end loop;
commit;
end;
```

Is preferably store only the records you will need instead of inserting and deleting.
Only make sure your condition in the "IF" let pass only the records you need